# Matlab (Linux): mp4 video loading

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu, video, mp4

I'm trying to load an mp4 video with Matlab with:

```
  robj=VideoReader('ball moving.mp4')
```

I receive the following error:

> Error using VideoReader/init (line 450)
>
> ***The VideoReader plugin libmwgstreamerplugin failed to load***
> ***properly.***
>
> *Error in VideoReader (line 147)*
>
> *obj.init(fileName);*

Matlab (R2013a) is running on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS). Something is wrong in the installation, but what is it?

Comment: I assume you've installed [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/)? You need version 0.10 or later, I believe. You might try re-installing it.

Comment: I installed Gstreamer, the version 1.0, not 0.10. I have added a lot of packages, in case something was missing, but  nothing changed. I will try to remove and reinstall gstreamer, the new version, and then the older. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading gstreamer packages from version 1.0 to 0.10 "solved" the issue.
Maybe because package *gstreamer-x-ffmpeg* is required (only found for version x=0.10, in *ppa:mc3man/trusty-media*).

Answer (score 0):

Install ffmpeg and use this function:

```
function v=readVideo(path_file)

system(['rm /tmp/video_tmp.avi']);
system(['ffmpeg -i ' path_file ' -vcodec copy -acodec copy /tmp/video_tmp.avi']);

v = VideoReader('/tmp/video_tmp.avi')

end
```